# Where are the status and getheader attributes of urllib.error.HTTPError coming from?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, urllib

I have this code.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.error

try:
    urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.example.com/foo')
except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
    print(type(e))
    print(e.status)
    print(e.getheader('Content-Type'))
    print(e.getheader('Content-Length'))
```

When I run this, I get this output.

```
$ python3 url.py
<class 'urllib.error.HTTPError'>
404
text/html
1270
```

I want to know where the `status` and `getheader` attributes of `urllib.error.HTTPError` are defined?

Here are the details of my Python interpreter.

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.4.2
$ python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
['', '/usr/lib/python3.4', '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

To find out where `status` and `getheader` attributes could be coming from, I checked individual Python modules in the Python library.

```
$ cd /usr/lib/python3.4/
$ grep "class HTTPError" urllib/error.py
class HTTPError(URLError, urllib.response.addinfourl):
$ grep "class URLError" urllib/error.py 
class URLError(OSError):
$ grep "class add" urllib/response.py 
class addbase(tempfile._TemporaryFileWrapper):
class addclosehook(addbase):
class addinfo(addbase):
class addinfourl(addinfo):
$ grep "class _TemporaryFileWrapper" tempfile.py 
class _TemporaryFileWrapper:
$ grep -E "status|getheader" urllib/error.py urllib/response.py tempfile.py 
urllib/error.py:responses, with a status code, headers, and a body.  In some contexts,
$ python3 -c "import urllib.error; print(dir(urllib.error.HTTPError))" | grep -E "status|getheader"
$ python3 -c "import urllib.error; print(dir(OSError))" | grep -E "status|getheader"
$
```

Answer (score -2):

You can just type the name of an imported Python module in the interpreter to see the filename:

```
>>> import urllib.error
>>> urllib.error
<module 'urllib.error' from '/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/error.py'>
```

The file will redirect you to `response.py` → `addinfourl` then.

Comment: Did you read my question entirely? I know that `urllib.error` comes from urllib/error.py. Did you actually open urllib/error.py and find whether the attributes `status` or `getheader` are defined anywhere in this file? They are not. See the output of `grep -E "status|getheader" urllib/error.py urllib/response.py tempfile.py` that I have included in the question. It returns no results.